# Could not parse mapping document

Tags: java, hibernate

There's some problem in the mapping file which I'm unable to find. It give a NullPointerException

Tried changing the tags. Still the problem persists. The mapping file is below.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name = "model.Order" table = "USER_ORDER">

<id name = "orderId" type = "int" column = "ID" not-null = "true">
<generator class = "native"/>
</id>

<property name = "quantity" type = "int" column = "QUANTITY"/>
<property name = "cost" type = "int" column = "COST"/>
<property name = "status" type = "boolean" column = "STATUS"/>
<property name = "createdDate" type = "string" column = "CREATED"/>
<property name = "modifiedDate" type = "string" column = "MODIFIED"/>

<many-to-one name = "user" class = "model.User" column = "USER_ID"   
cascade = "save-update"  not-null = "true"/>
<set name = "orderDetail" cascade = "save-update" inverse = "false">
<key column = "ORDER_ID" not-null = "true"/>
<one-to-many class = "model.OrderDetails"/>
</set>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

> Database Connection Creation Failed : Could not parse mapping
>       document: /mapping/Order.hbm.xml (RESOURCE)
>       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at db.DatabaseConnectionH.getSession(DatabaseConnectionH.java:39)
>         at dao.CartDao.getCarts(CartDao.java:72)
>         at services.CartServices.getUserCarts(CartServices.java:55)
>         at controller.CartController.checkCarts(CartController.java:214)
>         at MainMenu.main(MainMenu.java:87)

Comment: Have you forgotten your mapping for Carts in the Order.hbm.xml file? Because that is throwing a NPE.

Comment: Please add the Java code that throws the `NullPointerException` to your question. Thanks.

Comment: No The cart is not needed in Order map. The null pointer is thrown only because of the order mapping. I've tested it.

Comment: Above file is the order mapping I've done. Nothing more. The trace which i gave before is what i get always. Can you suggest any points which I might have missed

Comment: Have you specified the entire path as `<mapping resource="com/company/project/some.hbm.xml"></mapping>` in your  `hibernate.cfg.xml` ?